# COLLADA Files Viewer

Tags: 3d, collada, sketchup

**UPDATE**: looks like it's my own fault for not studying enough SketchUp's GUI. See my own answer.

Hi,

I'm planning to implement an "export to COLLADA" functionality in [my mapping software](http://maperitive.net), but I'm hampered by a lack of a good COLLADA files viewer. I've tried several applications:

1. **Google SketchUp** provides the best viewing experience I've come across so far, but importing COLLADA files is very slow. I tried [this sample I found](http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/details?mid=edb44c07a55682f121fafe1eef0f95e), but it takes 2-3 minutes to load it into SketchUp, and I'm running this on a decent machine. Since developing an export code involves a lot of trials and errors, SketchUp is just too slow for experimental work.
2. I've tried **Blender**, but the user interface is pretty alien for someone not doing day-to-day 3D games development. But I have to praise it for being able to load the sample file almost instantly, which makes me think SketchUp guys either do some deliberate slowing down of the import in the free version or they need to freshen up on their programming skills. (**UPDATE**: it turns out you **can** load it fast, see my answer, Sorry guys.)
3. I also tried some other free viewers, but they are either not showing the sample properly or they have very limited viewing capabilities (no panning or orbiting, for example).

I'd be grateful for any hints, but I'm looking for first-hand experience, not just googling (I've tried that myself). I realize this is not a typical programming question, but I see no better place on StackExchange to ask this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been working on a program called [meshtool](https://github.com/pycollada/meshtool). You can load and view a collada file like this:

```
meshtool --load_collada file.dae --viewer
```

The [pycollada](https://github.com/pycollada/pycollada) library has gotten pretty good. Almost all collada files I've come across in the wild are supported properly.

Admittedly, the meshtool program is in its infancy, so I haven't written good installation instructions yet. You will need to have python 2.5+, numpy, panda3d, PIL, and lxml installed. If you let me know your platform, I can give some more detailed instructions.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, but I have to admit installing 6 software packages in order to view a file is not what I was looking for. Keep up the good work, though.

Comment: Agreed! The plan is to eventually package it up with a nice installer for windows, mac, and linux. Until then, it is what it is :) Good luck with your collada exporter.

Comment: meshtool looks nice, but it is not usable as a Collada viewer: requires a so called “direct.task” module, which seems provided by Panda3D only, which in turn cannot be installed on Ubuntu, because Panda3D is too old (require avcodec52, while modern Ubuntu have avcodec53). Would be better without dependencies to Panda3D.

Comment: @Hibou57 you can install the .deb manually from http://www.panda3d.org/download.php?sdk&version=devel

Comment: @JTerrace. Thanks for the pointer. I was first disappointed to see it's all for AMD64, but then I found there is an unstable for Oneiric, which is close to Precise: http://www.panda3d.org/download.php?platform=ubuntu&version=1.8.0&sdk

By the way, here is a pointer I feel worth to share here:
http://www.subdude-site.com/WebPages_Local/RefInfo/Computer/Linux/LinuxGuidesByBlaze/apps3Dtools/3D_viewers-converters/3Dsoftware/3D_viewers_notesANDcode.htm

P.S. My apologizes for such a long URL.

Comment: Wow, that's an impressive list

Comment: I managed to install panda3d 1.9 as well on ubuntu quantal. But still, I get "Warning: filter 'sander_simplify' disabled because of ImportError: No module named networkx" after which I get a traceback which ends in -  "File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py", line 178, in unique
    perm = ar.argsort(kind='mergesort')
TypeError: requested sort not available for type
"
Any help here?

Comment: What version of numpy do you have? You might have to upgrade

Comment: Yes, you were right about the numpy version. Thanks. I've updated to version 1.7.1 from 1.6.2. But still, when I try the viewer I get a blank panda window. I've confirmed that panda 3d works for me. 
Now, when I try to run meshtool with collada_viewer on a dae file I get "Known pipe types: glxGraphicsPipe (all display modules loaded.) :display:glxdisplay(warning): No suitable FBConfig contexts available; using XVisual only. depth_bits=24 color_bits=24 alpha_bits=8 stencil_bits=8 back_buffers=1 force_hardware=1" as the output followed by grey blank panda window.

Answer (score 17):

There is also [**MeshLab**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MeshLab) which is free and open-source, cross-platform (Windows, Mac OS X, Linux), it supports [several formats](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/meshlab/index.php?title=Supported_Formats) (COLLADA, VRML 2.0, 3DS etc.) and has extensive [viewing capabilities](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/meshlab/index.php?title=Interacting_with_the_mesh) (e.g. panning/orbiting).

[image: MeshLab example]

Answer (score 7):

Well it turns out SketchUp is slow because it validates the COLLADA file when importing. You can turn it off:

1. Select **File | Import...** menu.
2. Click on the **Options** button in the **Open** dialog.
3. Uncheck **Validate COLLADA file** checkbox.

Maybe a suggestion to SketchUp developers: either make this option more visible or turn it off by default.

Answer (score 2):

[GLC_Player](http://www.glc-player.net/) is definitely also worth mentioning. Multi-platform, pretty fast and with a handy album function for viewing lots of files (you can open an entire folder hierarchy) with it.

Answer (score 2):

Photoshop (at least since CS4) can open and view COLLADA files.

Answer (score 2):

The  [open asset import library](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/) has a standalone viewer, [AssimpView](http://sourceforge.net/projects/assimp/files/assimp-3.0/), which I've been using to test an exporter I'm working on. It's fast and has some useful options for debugging. It also gives decent error messages when you screw something up, which has been a huge help.

Answer (score 1):

I have created collada-viewer, an HTML5 app that brings together ColladaLoader.js, three.js, and HTML5 File API to allow easy persistent storage and loading of 3D models in the COLLADA file format.

http://www.ravenrend.com/2012/11/26/collada-viewer/

Should make viewing of multiple files pretty easy, that was the idea.

Comment: the website is down but you can see the full source at https://github.com/csbrandt/collada-viewer

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vanda Engine to load your scenes in COLLADA format and convert them to real time scenes. [This is their website](http://vandaengine.com).

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded it from autodesk:

http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/item?siteID=123112&id=20481519

(if link is not working: http://www.autodesk.com/products/fbx/overview)

fbx converter include dae collada viewer

Answer (score 1):

If you accept commercial tools, the best solution to view a COLLADA file is using Autodesk 3ds Max or Maya with [OpenCollada](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCOLLADA) plugin. It has support for COLLADA version 1.4.1 and 1.5, and gives better results then all free viewers in my experience.

Another possibility might be the [Unity](https://unity3d.com/). Actually, it is not viewer, but a game engine. Nevertheless, it can import COLLADA files really succesfully.

Answer (score 1):

COLLADA had now been replaced by glTF format.

[F3D](https://gitlab.kitware.com/f3d/f3d/-/releases) can open glTF and many other file format.
F3D is a free, opensource VTK based software.

```
f3d file.gltf
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also MeshLab which is free and open-source, cross-platform (Windows, Mac OS X, Linux), it supports several formats (COLLADA, VRML 2.0, 3DS etc.) and has extensive viewing capabilities (e.g. panning/orbiting).